# On which StackExchange site would a question about POSIX standards be most appropriate?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about the POSIX standards (specifically whether it specifies a particular location and name for the POSIX shell that is required to be available on all POSIX compliant systems).

Where should such a question be posted?

On the one hand it's related to programming (StackOverflow) ... as it related to a coding specification. On another tentacle it's also related to the administration of Unix like systems.  (FHS for Linux specifies that "[If /bin/sh is not a true Bourne shell, it must be a hard or symbolic link to the real shell command](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html)." --- which is fine for most practical purposes.  But I'd prefer to be able to quote chapter and verse from POSIX if necessary.

Comment: This is a side issue, but honestly, any case where FHS is "fine for most practical purposes", I can't see how POSIX would be relevant at all. If you don't care about non-FHS systems, who cares what POSIX says? (Except in the rare case where you think you've found a bug in the FHS design itself.)

Answer (score 7):

I think https://unix.stackexchange.com/ should be perfectly fine, regardless of whether you think it might also nominally fit on some other sites.  There are 111 questions with the [posix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/posix) tag, and 2,525 hits on the search term with or without the pertinent tag.